# OpenTK GetActiveUniform handle is invalid

Tags: c#, glsl, opentk

I'm trying to get all uniforms whithin a GLSL program, but GL.GetActiveUniform is throwing an error :

> {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070006): The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeHGlobal(IntPtr hglobal)    at OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.GetActiveUniform(UInt32 program, UInt32 index, Int32 bufSize, Int32& length, Int32& size, ActiveUniformType& type, StringBuilder name)}

Here's my code :

```
int count = 0;

GL.GetProgram(_shader.id, GetProgramParameterName.ActiveUniforms, out count);

for (uint i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder name = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    int length = 0,
    size = 0;
    ActiveUniformType uniformType;

    GL.GetActiveUniform((uint)(_shader.id), i, 120, out length, out size, out uniformType, name);
    int location = GL.GetUniformLocation(_shader.id, name.ToString());

    AddUniform(name.ToString().Replace(" ", ""), new Uniform(location, uniformType));
}
```

Comment: This seams to happen when trying to get a mat4 uniform.

Comment: Probably you have to set the capacity of `name` (see [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)) e.g. `name = new System.Text.StringBuilder(120);` - See further [Resolved - GLControl crach no exception](https://github.com/opentk/opentk/issues/515)

Comment: that worked! thankx